# Get author information in yith woocommerce wishlist premium

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I hope you can help me. I don't know much about PHP code.
I am testing **yith woocommerce wishlist premium plugin**, and in wishlist-view.php file
I have placed the following PHP code, but it only shows the information of the current user, not the author of the wishlist.

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'Name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'LastName: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
?>
```

I would love to show the author information of the list. So when the list is shared by url, another user can see the user meta data of whoever created the whislist.
The author meta data I would like to see is name (user_firstname), email (user_email) and profile picture (get_avatar)

I hope you can help me
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the wishlist user/author ID from the `$wishlist` object which is available in template files, then from that ID you can get the user data using the `get_userdata` function and you can print the information.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Get wishlist user/author ID.
$wishlist_user_id = $wishlist->get_user_id();

// Check if the user is not empty.
if ( ! empty( $wishlist_user_id ) ) {
    // Get wishlist user data.
    $wishlist_user = get_userdata( absint( $wishlist_user_id ) );
    // Check if a user is found.
    if ( ! empty( $wishlist_user ) ) {
        // Write the information.
        echo '<p>Email: ' . esc_html( $wishlist_user->user_email ) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>First Name: ' . esc_html( $wishlist_user->first_name ) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Last Name: ' . esc_html( $wishlist_user->last_name ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent thank you very much!!!. and by the way what would be the PHP code to get the profile picture

Comment: You can use [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/) but if you have any other setup for profile picture then you'll have to get it on a the way you implemented the profile picture feature.

Comment: I already have [this code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YmZrzXvZkl5Yhrbkz97IgZvf10rRCsLcDh1cGt5mXiI/edit?usp=sharing) to get the profile picture, but it only work for the current user. 


I would like to show the author profile picture of the wishlist.
Thank you very much for your cordially support.

Comment: modify your code and use the wishlist id as I have explained in my answer, not the current user id.